# dealing with inf in list

Tags: python, list, numpy, infinity

I have a list that I am trying to solve for a variable but is not working because I have inf in some of the elements in the list. How can I deal with the inf in the values so that I can solve for my variable m? When I run the code it says "Cannot convert 0 to int" so the solve command has an issue with the inf values in the list of A.

```
from sympy import *
from numpy import inf
m = var('m')
A = [inf*m - 1, inf*m - 2, .1122*m - 7, 0.054*m - 8]
m = [solve(eq,m) for eq in A]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's usually not a good idea to mix `sympy` and `numpy`. Sympy uses `oo` for infinity. You can use `.subs` to replace the `inf` with `oo`:

```
from sympy import *
from numpy import inf
m = var('m')
A = [inf*m - 1, inf*m - 2, .1122*m - 7, 0.054*m - 8]
sol = [solve(eq.subs(inf, oo), m) for eq in A]
```

`sol` is `[[nan], [nan], [62.3885918003565], [148.148148148148]]`

Comment: Actually the A list is an output of a function that I did not include for simplicity. The list of A has the inf as I originally posted so is there a way I can get nan when inf is involved?

Comment: It's always a good idea to include code which is as close to the actual problem as possible. I've changed the code to substitute the `inf` for `oo`, but I still recommend the best way to solve the problem is to avoid mixing `numpy` and `sympy` (so to change the function which returns this list to use `oo` instead of `inf`).